# Having a single image view to show different images

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

My app requires characters except they can be customized. Is it possible to have one image view but change the actual image to something else?

Here is an example: There is item 1 and item 2. item 1 is default. If i click to buy item 2, the image view of showing item 1 is replaced with the picture of item 2.

Is there any way I can do this and if not how do developers have customization like that?

Comment: [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImageView/image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am missing something, it seems as simple as:

```
UIImageView *myImg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myFirstImage"]];
```

And if you want to change the image to `myOtherImage`, you can set as below

```
[myImg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myOtherImage"]];
```

If you need the image to be a component, then you could subClass UIImageView and call functions to swap between images.

Comment: Lol hopefully I will not get to much hate for this comment because I lost a good chunk of my reputation posting this thread but, is @"myOtherImage" the actual name in the supporting files folder?

Comment: @"myFirstImage" and @"myOtherImage" are the names you gave your images in the Images.xcassets asset catalog. If you aren't using a catalog then they are the image names of your image files less the file extension.